# Guardar varios valores em campo da tabela mysql

Tags: mysql

Queria arrumar um jeito de guardar, por exemplo, os códigos de uns médicos que participaram de uma consulta de um animal.

Queria guardar mais de um veterinário na consulta.(quantos for necessario)

```
create table if not exists consulta(
codConsulta character(8) not null primary key,
crv character(5) ,
codAnimal character(8) not null,
diagnostico text not null,
constraint fk_crv foreign key (crv) references veterinario(crv),
constraint fk_codAnimal foreign key (codAnimal) references animal(codAnimal))engine=INNODB default charset = utf8;
```

Comment: Leia sobre Normalização de Dados (Formas Nornais) , está no caminho errado acredite.

Answer (score 2):

A melhor maneira seria ter três tabelas (consulta, veterinario e veterinario_consulta ).
A tabela veterinario_consulta seria **n para n** guardando os códigos da consulta e veterinário

N para N (explicação)

https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/help/18/fmp/pt/index.html#page/FMP_Help/many-to-many-relationships.html

Fiz um exemplo funcionando em http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b94c3c/5

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `veterinario` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(80) NOT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `veterinario` (`id`, `nome`) VALUES
  ('1', 'Carlos Manga'),
  ('2', 'Leonardo Pires'),  
  ('3', 'João Duarte');
  
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cliente` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(80) NOT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `cliente` (`id`, `nome`) VALUES
  ('1', 'Fernando'),
  ('2', 'Maria Inês'),  
  ('3', 'Carmem');
  
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `consulta` (
  `id_consulta` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id_cliente` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `dt_consulta` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_consulta`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `consulta` (`id_consulta`, `id_cliente`, `dt_consulta`) VALUES
  ('1', '1','2020-05-05'),
  ('2', '1','2020-05-13'),  
  ('3', '3','2020-05-27'),
  ('4', '2','2020-06-02'),
  ('5', '4','2020-06-30'),  
  ('6', '5','2020-07-16');
  
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `veterinario_consulta` (
  `id_consulta` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id_veterinario` varchar(80) NOT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_consulta`,`id_veterinario`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `veterinario_consulta` (`id_consulta`, `id_veterinario`) VALUES
  ('1', '2'),
  ('1', '3'),  
  ('2', '1'),    
  ('3', '2'),
  ('3', '3'),  
  ('4', '2'),
  ('5', '1'),  
  ('3', '1');
```

Exemplo consulta

```
select c.id_consulta, l.nome cliente, v.nome veterinario
  from consulta c,
       veterinario_consulta vc,
       cliente l,
       veterinario v
 where c.id_consulta    = vc.id_consulta
  and  v.id             = vc.id_veterinario
  and  c.id_cliente     = l.id
```

Você pode retornar os veterinários em uma linha também usando group_concat

https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php

```
select c.id_consulta, l.nome cliente, group_concat(v.nome) veterinario
  from consulta c,
       veterinario_consulta vc,
       cliente l,
       veterinario v
 where c.id_consulta    = vc.id_consulta
  and  v.id             = vc.id_veterinario
  and  c.id_cliente     = l.id
  group by c.id_consulta, l.nome
```

Comment: mas se a consulta tiver mais de um veterinário ?

Comment: No exemplo que fiz acima http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b94c3c/5 a primeira consulta possui dois veterinários, conforme as duas primeiras linha no retorno.

Comment: Julgo ser interessante deixar claro que "melhor" é completamente relativo. Nem sempre a normalização é, de fato, a melhor forma. É bem comum, inclusive, vermos o processo de desnormalização dos bancos para otimização. Talvez sugerir a normalização inicialmente por questões de facilidade de manutenção faça mais sentido.

Comment: Se deve conhecer as Formas Normais para se decidir não usá-las. Neste caso então não vejo motivo para não ser conservador, desnomarlizar só vai gerar consultas e cadastros complicados à toa.